# Find a Storyboard instance generated dynamically (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, storyboard

I have a problem for finding a generated storyboard with its name.
I can't use a class variable because this code is called several times and the return is asynchronous.

You can see my other question for more information: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10814491/wpf-storyboard-doesnt-begin-if-stop-is-called-after-processing)

My code:

```
private void refreshPostIt(int index)
    {
        Button btn = // Button to rotate
        Storyboard sb = new Storyboard();
        sb.Name = "sb" + postItIndex;

        Storyboard.SetTarget(rotate, btn);
        Storyboard.SetTargetName(rotate, btn.Name);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(rotate, new PropertyPath("(UIElement.RenderTransform).(RotateTransform.Angle)"));
        sb.Children.Add(rotate);
        sb.Begin(btn, true);

        // Asynchronous call
        BackgroundWorker bgw = new BackgroundWorker();
        bgw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bgw_DoWork);
        bgw.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(bgw_RunWorkerCompleted);
        bgw.RunWorkerAsync(postItIndex);
    }
private void bgw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        int postItIndex = // Retrieved from e.Arguments
        Button btn = // Find the Button thanks to the postItIndex

        Storyboard sb = // Here is my problem, how to find the Storyboard
        if (sb != null)
        {
            // Stop rotation
            //sb.Stop(btn);
        }
    }
```

Comment: you have this problem because you are not using MVVM. If your viewmodel had a collection of "postIt" where each one would have a IsRefreshing property, you could BeginStoryBoard and Stop it. I'll post an answer which explains how to set up the xaml but adapting the collection and the UI to be databound is on you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could always create a class that inherits from BackgroundWorker, it's not sealed. Add a property to that class that contains whatever information you want to pass on to the completed event.

```
    class StoryboardWorkerArgs
    {
        public Storyboard StoryBoard { get; set; }
        public object Other { get; set; }
    }

    class BackgroundWorker2 : BackgroundWorker
    {
        public StoryboardWorkerArgs Args { get; set; }
    }
```

You can then set your storyboard in the args propety.

```
BackgroundWorker2 worker = new BackgroundWorker2();
worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(worker_DoWork);
worker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(worker_RunWorkerCompleted);
worker.Args = new StoryboardWorkerArgs ()
{
  StoryBoard = null, /* reference to your storyboard*/
  Other = null, /* postItIndex */
 };
 worker.RunWorkerAsync();
```

Then in your completed event.

```
void worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    BackgroundWorker2 sender2 = sender as BackgroundWorker2;
    if (sender2 != null)
    {
        var story = sender2.Args.StoryBoard; // <- your storyboard.
    }
}
```

Comment: Great, your solution works fine.
However I modified it with just an arguments class which I pass to the caller. Thank you

Comment: Great, if you used one of the answers from the page please mark for others. If you found your own way to achieve the result please add it as an answer and mark it so others know how to solve the problem if they come across it.

Answer (score 1):

If you were using MVVM to display "postIt"-s starting and stopping the storyboards would be completely in XAML.

have the following pseudostyle in the UIItem dataTemplate representing the Post:

```
<Style>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsRefreshing}"
                     Value="True">
            <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                <BeginStoryboard x:Name="rotating">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation... />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
            <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="rotating" />
            </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

You viewmodel should be soemthing like (pseudocode):

```
Class MyApp : INotifyPropertyChanged
  ObservableCollection<Post> Posts {get;set;}
  void RefreshPost(int id);

Class Post : INotifyPropertyChanged
  bool IsRefreshing {get;set;}
```

In the window have a listBox with the ItemTemplate for you Post, and give it ItemsSource the Posts collection.

And the datacontext of the window set to an instance of MyApp.
So whenever you changed IsRrefreshing of some post the UI would do the rest.